# List browsers with TestCafe

Tags: command-line, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

Is there a documentation about how to call command-line functions from testcafe with the API? Like

```
testcafe -b
```

A link or sample script will really help.

Comment: Do you mean list of supported browsers and how to call them from cmd line?

Comment: No, my concern ist to get the list of browsers in my node module.

Comment: So, after command line call in your code you want to get names of all browsers that was in that call?

Comment: I know how to call the commandline and receive the result. This is not the problem. I want to avoid to mix commandline and API usage in my node module. The problem I have, I cannot receive the list by API but by commandline.

Comment: Not sure if this is a public api, but here what command line is doing: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/6083a384134c24095aca389ff61e977ce337d87f/src/cli/cli.js#L124-L144

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present, it's possible to get a browser list only via a command-line API.
I've created a suggestion for this case in the TestCafe repository - https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3919. Track it to be informed about our progress.

Answer (score 0):

Late on this, but you can get the supported browsers via API as follows

```
const browserTools = require('testcafe-browser-tools');
const installedBrowsers = browserTools.getInstallations(); // return a promise
```